# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, backend

I create two view for one component in `joomla` for backend. When I create my first View it is display properly,but when I create my second View I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\administrator\components\com_machine\views\machinecategories\tmpl\default.php on line 14

and in my `default.php` on line 14 I declare this for second view.

```
$listOrder  = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));  //Line 14
$listDirn   = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction')); //Line 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

In **default.php** there is no mistake.but in my **model file** i make mistake in my model name..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a starter joomla developer. I hope this helps you a bit. Get the jdbg plugin (free) for joomla. It has krumo (a very nice looking print_r). After you installed the plugin, use it in your code as `jdbg::p($this->state);` It will print all properties about `$this->state`. Before calling for `$listOrder  = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));` use the `jdbg` then use a `die();`. Maybe the `$this->state;` is not initialised or set in the view. Try to use debug methods too, like xdebug or print the `debug_backtrace();` on the template with jdbg.